# Tensorflow Slim Imagenet training

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to prepare the date to train an ImageNet model from scratch and I am a bit confused about how the training works.

While preparing the TF records I noticed this file inside the Inception model data directory: "imagenet_metadata.txt". The file holds labels for 21842 classes yet the training script and "imagenet_lsvrc_2015_synsets.txt" file only works for 1000 classes.

I am wondering what modifications I need to do to train the model on the 21K classes not the 1K one?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite straightforward with slim.To Train imgnet 21k with slim I recommend to do the following steps:

1.In tf_models/slim/datasets Folder create a copy of imagenet.py File ( for example imgnet.py).In the new file Change the required
    Variables to your desired Values:

```
    _FILE_PATTERN = ####your tfrecord_file_pattern. for me('imgnet_%s_*.tfrecord')
    _SPLITS_TO_SIZES = {
        'train': ####Training Samples,
        'validation': ####Validation Samples,}
    _NUM_CLASSES = 21841
```

*the wordnet synset contains 21482 entries but the total number of classes in imagenet21k in 21481 (n04399382 is missed).so be sure about the total number of available classes.

*Also you need to do a little modification in code in order to load the synset files from your local address.

```
    base_url = '/home/snf/libraries/tf_models/slim'
    synset_url = '{}/listOfTags.txt'.format(base_url)
    synset_to_human_url = '{}/imagenet21k_metadata.txt'.format(base_url)
```

1. Add the new dataset to datasetfactory.py in tf_models/slim/datasets :

   ```
   from datasets import imgnet
   datasets_map = {
   'cifar10': cifar10,
   'flowers': flowers,
   'imagenet': imagenet,
   'mnist': mnist,
   'imgnet': imgnet, #add this line to dataset_map

   }
   ```
2. In tf_models/slim/ create Train_Imgnet.sh File  containing these lines:

   ```
   TRAIN_DIR=trained/imgnet-inception-v4
   DATASET_DIR=/media/where/tfrecords/saved/tfRecords-fall11_21k
   CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0,1,2,3" python train_image_classifier.py 

     --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
     --dataset_name=imgnet \
     --dataset_split_name=train \
     --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
     --model_name=inception_v4 \
     --max_number_of_steps=10000000 \
     --batch_size=32 \
     --learning_rate=0.01 \
     --learning_rate_decay_type=fixed \
     --save_interval_secs=60 \
     --save_summaries_secs=60 \
     --log_every_n_steps=100 \
     --optimizer=rmsprop \
     --weight_decay=0.00004\
     --num_readers=12 \
     --num_clones=4
   ```
3. set the file to executable (Chmod +x Train_Imgnet.sh ) and run it (./Train_Imgnet.sh )